# How to run schedule tasks every minute in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, schedule

How i can run my Schedule task every minute? When i run command `php artisan schedule:run`, console get "No scheduled commands are ready to run.". How i should set my Tasks properly? For example if I use solo command `php artisan command:send_info_email_before_event` it works, but i want do it with `schedule:run` when i develop app.

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('command:send_info_email_before_event')
         ->everyMinute();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be setting this up via **cron job** to run every minute. Task scheduling is not intended to be run manually.

In the terminal run:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Once saved, this will then run the application scheduler every minute (without you needing to run `php artisan schedule:run`.

[See the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling) for more information.

Comment: How i should test my Tasks properly on localhost?

Comment: You can test the `Task` works by manually running the task in the terminal. In your instance, run `php artisan command:send_info_email_before_event`

Answer (score 2):

In windows you can schedule a task.

1. Open the Windows start menu and type in "**Scheduled Tasks**". This will
   open the Task Scheduler.  After that click Create Task (I would not
   suggest using basic task, as it is too basic for cron jobs).
2. This will open a window that allows you to create a new "Cron Job" in Windows 10.

   **Name**: This is an easy way for you to remember what that task does. You can enter anything.

   **Description**: Just a more in-depth description for you to remember what it is.

   **User Account**: I would suggest using a full privileged account so that your cron jobs can create and modify files if it needs to. But I would also suggest using an account dedicated to Cron jobs so that you can revoke permissions any time you need to!

   **Due to the nature** of a website, I would definitely check “Run when user is logged in or not” and leave do not store password (This can throw an XML invalid error if you leave this unchecked and a password is required)

   **And I would also check** "Run with Highest Privileges"
3. After that, Click "**Trigger**" and "**Add new**"
4. To run a "Cron Job" task that runs more than once a day, Click **Daily task**. **Recure daily**, and **repeat the task every minute**. Be sure to click enabled. After that click Okay and click the tab "Actions" and New…
5. Set program/Script to the /path/to/php.exe and arguments to /path/to/artisan schedule run. Be sure to use "" if you have spaces in the path. I would suggest using them either way as a rule of thumb.

Remember to not use production email credentials, you can use something like https://mailtrap.io to "trap" all sent emails.

Comment: I updated the response, this will run the cron like it it was the linux crontab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954322/14344959