# My Schedular is not calling everyMinute()

Tags: laravel, lumen

My schedular is not calling automatically after every minute.

I have tried following code

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('timestamp:minute')->everyMinute();
}
```

I need that my schedular will call automatically.

Comment: Did you setup the cron job on your machine? `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: I am new to it, can you please elaborate, how to setup i.e where to write the above line mentioned by you

Comment: You can try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run schedule tasks every minute in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429636/how-to-run-schedule-tasks-every-minute-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your terminal, type `crontab -e` and add below line at the end

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php{php_version} /path_to_project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now, in terminal, go to your project directory and run once

```
php artisan schedule:run
```